# pylab, plot x-axis with same length using aspect_ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib, aspect-ratio

I want to plot two axes with the same X and different Y datasets. Additionally i need to plot the second one with the same dimension in both x & y (so i used set_aspect('equal')). I did the following:

```
import pylab as plt

n = 50
x = range(n)

y1 = plt.randn(n)
y2 = y1 * 10


ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1.plot(x, y1, 'ro')
ax1.set_xlabel('distance [km]')
ax1.set_ylabel('elevation [km]')

ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'ro')
ax2.set_xlabel('distance [km]')
ax2.set_ylabel('elevation [km]')
ax2.set_aspect('equal')


plt.show()
```

and the results is:
[image: plot result]

After doing this, the problem is, the first x-axis's length is different from the second one. How can i edit my code to get the same length for two axes?
Note: I dont use "sharex" because it sets the second axis based on the first one, while i want the the first obey from the second one.

Comment: Removing the line `ax2.set_aspect('equal')` did it for me.

Comment: `set_aspect('equal')` ensures both axis have the same scale, not the same dimension. Are you sure you want to use it? And what do "same dimension" and "same lenght" exactly mean? Same number of pixels, same lenght in km, same range of km...?

Comment: Actually, i mean the same scale. for example 1 km in X-axis should be equal (in length and pixel) in Y-axis.